# Rough edges in windows using tkinter canvas

Tags: python, windows, macos, graphics, tkinter

I'm trying to create some basic charts using tkinter for a GUI that works both on OSX and Windows. I'm drawing arcs on a canvas to create a pie chart which displays perfectly on OSX, but on windows I see rough edges particularly on the curves themselves

[Canvas displayed on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA7Ea.png)

[Canvas display on OSX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY9ta.png)

Any ideas how to improve the appearance of these graphics under windows?

Comment: check out this post about drawing anti-aliased graphics in windows http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-aggdraw.htm